# why can't I login to facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails

it is not letting me login to facebook at all it said there is and errors like null pointer exception attempt to invoke virtual method I just want it fixes so I can talk to my family and my sister that lives in Australia

Answer (score 0):

Sound like you have spyware on your PC.  Better question for superuser.